# How to check that an encrypted disk was previously open using cryptsetup?

Tags: shell, ubuntu, encryption

I am writing a shell script (meant to work with Ubuntu only) that assumes that a disk has been previously open (using the command below) to make operations on it (`resize2fs`, `lvcreate`, ...). However, this might not always be the case, and when the disk is closed, the user of the script has to run this line before running the script, asking for his/her passphrase:

```
sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdaX sdaX_crypt
```

Ideally, the script should start with this command, simplifying the user sequence. However, if the disk was indeed already opened, the script will fail because an encrypted disk cannot be opened twice.

How can I check if the disk was previously open? Is checking that `/dev/mapper/sdX_crypt` exists a valid solution / enough? If not or not possible, is there a way to make the command run only if necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I could not find a better solution, I went ahead and chose the "check if the device exists" one.

The encrypted disk embeds a specific Volume Group (called `my-vg` for the example), so my working solution is:

```
if [ ! -b /dev/my-vg ]; then
  sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdaX sdaX_crypt
fi
```

---

I check that `/dev/my-vg` exists instead of `/dev/mapper/sda_cryptX` because every other command in my script uses the first one as an argument so I kept it for consistency, but I reckon that this solution below looks more encapsulated:

```
if [ ! -b /dev/mapper/sdaX_crypt ]; then
  sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdaX sdaX_crypt
fi
```

Although the solution I described above works for me, is there a good reason I should switch to the latter one or it doesn't matter?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the lsblk command.

If the disk is already unlocked, it will display two lines: the device and the mapped device, where the mapped device should be of type crypt.

```
# lsblk -l -n /dev/sdaX
sdaX   253:11   0   2G  0  part
sdaX_crypt (dm-6) 253:11   0   2G  0  crypt
```

If the disk is not yet unlocked, it will only show the device.

```
# lsblk -l -n /dev/sdaX
sdaX   253:11   0   2G  0  part
```

Comment: An advantage of lsblk is that it provides a mapping between the device path and the mapped name, in case you don't know it.

Answer (score 4):

I'd also suggest lsblk - but since I came here to find some relevant info I did find and thought I'd post here the following command as well:

```
#: cryptsetup status <device> | grep -qi active
```

Cheers

Comment: Maybe cryptsetup has changed, but now 'cryptsetup status' requires the mapped <name>, not the device path. Confirmed in the manual, and by testing (Debian Buster, cryptsetup 2:2.3.5-1~bpo10+1)

Comment: Be careful with that command.

`sudo cryptsetup status luksBackup | grep -iq 'is active'`

When a volume is not active the output of `cryptsetup` still matches against the `active` pattern passed to `grep`:

`/dev/mapper/volumeName is inactive.`

Answer (score 1):

```sh
cryptsetup status volumeName
echo $? # Exit status should be 0 (success).
```

If you want to avoid displaying `cryptsetup` output, you can redirect it to `/dev/null`.

```sh
cryptsetup status volumeName > /dev/null
echo $? # Exit status should be 0 (success).
```

This is a snippet from a script I wrote last night to take daily snapshots.

```sh
DEVICE=/dev/sdx
HEADER=/root/luks/arch/sdx-header.img
KEY_FILE=/root/luks/arch/sdx-key.bin
VOLUME=luksHome
MOUNTPOINT=/home
SUBVOLUME=@home

# Ensure encrypted device is active.
cryptsetup status "${VOLUME}" > /dev/null
IS_ACTIVE=$?

while [[ $IS_ACTIVE -ne 0 ]]; do
    printf "Volume '%s' does not seem to be active. Activate? [y/N]\n" $VOLUME
    read -N 1 -r -s

    if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]; then
        cryptsetup open --header="${HEADER}" --key-file="${KEY_FILE}" "${DEVICE}" "${VOLUME}"
        IS_ACTIVE=$?
    else
        exit 0
    fi
done
```